# R/ Can you teach me what 'b/St.Er.|P[|Z|>z]' mean saying?

Tags: r

[image]

hat 'b/St.Er.|P[|Z|>z]' mean saying?? I can't understand ...

And are these all coefficients valide statistically when \alpha is 5% ??

Answer (score 0):

The columns seems to be `b/St.Er.` = `Coefficient/(Standard Error)`. Then, the p-value is the P(|Z| > |b/St.Er.|), where `Z ~ N(0,1)`. It is the Wald test (https://www.ssc.wisc.edu/sscc/pubs/MM/MM_TestEffects.html)

Comment: Do you mean that they are p-value?? But, I know p-value is +(positive number). but, there are also -(negative number). can you explain more about it??

Comment: @김기억 No, the p-value is the probability that z is higher than that numbers for the normal distribution

Comment: thanks! I solved this.

Comment: The p-value is the *two*-sided p-value, $\Pr(|Z|\gt |b/se|).$

Comment: Indeed, in fact, it is well written in the question, with `|Z|` instead of `Z`. Thanks!

Comment: @김기억, also to clarify the p-value is the 6th column and is indeed positive. The 5th column is the test statistic. The 7th column (Mean of X) seems to be empty